# Битрикс ошибка 503?

Tags: битрикс

На сайте стоит 1С-Битрикс наблюдается странное поведение,
при открытии сразу большого количества страниц сайта в одном браузере выдаёт ошибку 503 и тут же другой открываешь и всё нормально.
Хостинг уверяет, что на их стороне ошибок нет.
Битрикс явных ошибок не выдаёт.
Может кто сталкивался с подобным, как решить проблему?

Comment: Агенты выполняются на кроне?

Comment: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/support/forum/forum6/topic8777/